# join two list in linq initializing properties one time

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have found many examples to join list in linq but my exact problem is not solved.

I have to join list List and List

i have initialized all properties of List and when joining i have to again initialize all properties of A and added properties from B.

```
List<A> listB = from c in country
                select new A
                {
                  CountryId=c.CountryId 
                  CountryName=c.CountryName  
                } ;
List<A> listA = from d in data
                select new A
                {
                  Name = d.Name
                  Age= d.Age,
                  City=d.City,
                  CountryId=d.CountryId   
                } ;
```

now to initialize Country property in List i am joining both list
**here the problem starts**

```
  listA = from d in listA
            join c in listB on d.CountryId=c.CountryId
                    select new A
                    {
                      Name = d.Name
                      Age= d.Age,
                      City=d.City,   
                      Country=c.CountryName
                    } ;
```

see in above join i have to again initialize Name, Age and City What i can do to initialize properties at one place.

Comment: You're not setting a `CountryId` on either of the lists. It's unclear what you're actually doing here... do you *have* to start with the lists, rather than doing the join in an original query?

Comment: sorry Jon, i have added

Comment: You should really consider to chose better names than `from d in listA
        join c in listB`. That's scary. Also, your `List<A>` actually are `IEnumerable<A>`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `listA` and `listB` - join countries and data directly:

```
from c in country
join d in data
   on c.CountryId equals d.CountryId 
select new A {
      Name = d.Name
      Age = d.Age,
      City = d.City,
      Country = c.CountryName
};
```

BTW why do you use `A` class for `listA` and `listB` if both contain different data? It should be **two different classes**.

Comment: no i have to fetch separately to prevent hits and joins. i have already country list

Comment: @user1750877 what do you mean by preventing hits and joins?

Comment: as i have already country list so i dont want to join for it to fetch from database

Comment: @user1750877 then you should create different classes for `listA` and `listB` - because those classes are not class `A`. And agree with Tim, naming is bad